# C# Importing CSV using OleDb

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, oledb

I'm trying to set up code to import `.CSV` files into .NET.

I've tried both `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` and `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` providers, including modifying the `Extended Properties` and even modifying corresponding registry keys for each. I have yet to come up with a solution for what I am attempting to do:

I would like to import each field as text, but leave fields longer than 255 characters un-truncated.

What I've found so far is that I can have one or the other, but not both.

- If I set the `ImportMixedTypes` registry value to `Majority Type`, it leaves 255+ character text fields un-truncated, but converts other fields to unwanted types.
- If I set the `ImportMixedTypes` registry value to `Text`, it truncates 255+ character text fields, but leaves the other field types as text.

How do I accomplish this using OleDb?

---

*Additional info:*

*I have a "notes" column, which can contain very lengthy text. I also have a "zip code" column, which contains mixed zip-code formats (5-digit and 9-digit with a dash). Typically, the 5-digit zip-code format is more popular, so the importer thinks that the column should be integer type, leaving the 9-digit zip-codes as null values after import.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something as versatile as the FileHelpers library (http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) instead?

Or alternatively if your requirements are no more than you state (read csv file, get string fields), use something really simple such as:

```
public static class SimpleCsvImport
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<string>> Import(string csvFileName)
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(csvFileName))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var fields = reader.ReadLine().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(f => f.Trim()).ToList();
                if (fields.Count > 0)
                    yield return fields;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented this code to read memo field (Microsoft Access):

```
  private string GetMemoField(string TableName, string FieldName, string IdentityFieldName, string IdentityFieldValue, OleDbConnection conn)
    {
        string ret = "";

        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT " + FieldName + " FROM “ + TableName + “ WHERE " + IdentityFieldName + "=" + IdentityFieldValue, conn);

                var reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);  // Create the DataReader that will get the memo field one buffer at a time

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            long numberOfChars = reader.GetChars(/*Field pos*/ 0, 0, null, 0, 0);   // Total number of memo field's chars

            if (numberOfChars > 0)
            {
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                char[] totalBuffer = new char[64*bufferSize];    // Array to hold memo field content

                long dataIndex = 0;

                do
                {

                    char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];   // Buffer to hold single read
                    long numberOfCharsReaded = reader.GetChars(0, dataIndex, buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    if (numberOfCharsReaded == 0)
                    {
                        ret = new string(totalBuffer,0, (int)numberOfChars);
                        break;
                    }

                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, totalBuffer, dataIndex, numberOfCharsReaded);     // Add temporary buffer to main buffer
                    dataIndex += numberOfCharsReaded;

                } while (true);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```